# C++ creating a std::vector from std::string array

Tags: c++, arrays, string, vector, std

I am learning about c++ and was following a course. A final exercise involves making a program for deck of cards. I have thought of an approach:

I initially tried to do everything with string arrays but realised that it would make more sense to use vectors since. I am now trying to create a std::vector std::string out of my std::string array but with no luck.

I have found some example code online such as:
[image]
from https://thispointer.com/5-different-ways-to-initialize-a-vector-in-c/

And tried to implement it for my program, however, I cannot get it to work and cant fully understand what is the issue.

My code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>




class card_deck {
public:
    card_deck();
    std::vector<std::string> deal_hand(int num_cards);
    void new_deck();
    

private:
    //std::vector<std::string> cards_vector;
    std::string cards[52] =
    {
        "As","2s","3s","4s","5s","6s","7s","8s","9s","Ts","Js","Qs","Ks",
        "Ah","2h","3h","4h","5h","6h","7h","8h","9h","Th","Jh","Qh","Kh",
        "Ad","2d","3d","4d","5d","6d","7d","8d","9d","Td","Jd","Qd","Kd",
        "Ac","2c","3c","4c","5c","6c","7c","8c","9c","Tc","Jc","Qc","Kc"
    };

    std::vector<std::string> cards_vector(cards, sizeof(cards)/sizeof(std::string) );
    
};
```

As you can see from my code, I initialize a string array in my private variables, and then want to convert this string array to std::vector

The error message returned:
[image]

**UPDATE**

**Code works when called in main()**

```
int main()
{
    std::string cards[52] =
    {
        "As","2s","3s","4s","5s","6s","7s","8s","9s","Ts","Js","Qs","Ks",
        "Ah","2h","3h","4h","5h","6h","7h","8h","9h","Th","Jh","Qh","Kh",
        "Ad","2d","3d","4d","5d","6d","7d","8d","9d","Td","Jd","Qd","Kd",
        "Ac","2c","3c","4c","5c","6c","7c","8c","9c","Tc","Jc","Qc","Kc"
    };

    // Initialize vector with a string array
    std::vector<std::string> vecOfStr(cards, cards + sizeof(cards) / sizeof(std::string));
    for (std::string str : vecOfStr)
        std::cout << str << std::endl;

}
```

**Does not work when used in class**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

class card_deck {
public:
    card_deck();
    std::vector<std::string> deal_hand(int num_cards);
    void new_deck();
    

private:

    std::string cards[52] =
    {
        "As","2s","3s","4s","5s","6s","7s","8s","9s","Ts","Js","Qs","Ks",
        "Ah","2h","3h","4h","5h","6h","7h","8h","9h","Th","Jh","Qh","Kh",
        "Ad","2d","3d","4d","5d","6d","7d","8d","9d","Td","Jd","Qd","Kd",
        "Ac","2c","3c","4c","5c","6c","7c","8c","9c","Tc","Jc","Qc","Kc"
    };

    // Initialize vector with a string array
    std::vector<std::string> vecOfStr(cards, cards + sizeof(cards) / sizeof(std::string));
    for (std::string str : vecOfStr)
        std::cout << str << std::endl;
    
};



int main()
{

}
```

Comment: Do not post compiler error messages as images please, but rather as verbatim, code formatted text. Also remove anyithing not relevant to reproduce the problem, you'll find guidance in the article describing the [mcve]. Ty for your cooperation.

Comment: `sizeof(cards)` -- Please print what this value is.  You may be surprised. (it isn't 52).

Comment: `std::vector<std::string> cards_vector(cards, cards + sizeof(cards));` -- Even though this line is not necessary, you did not follow the instructions at the link you posted.  To initialize a vector from an array would require `cards + sizeof(cards) / sizeof(std::string)`.  That's why the initial comment was made.

Comment: I see now.. However, that still returns the same error.  I have edited my initial code. I am not certain why it complains about ```member "card_deck::cards" is not a type name.```

Comment: Interesting : works when the code is called directly from main(). For some reason does not work in a class

Comment: @LukasPetrikas: That's due to *pointer decay*. Do it my way, all the problems go away.

Comment: Your "Does not work when used in class" snippet does not compile. Statements have to be in functions.

Comment: Rather than storing 52 strings, consider storing the mathematical value of the cards instead. For example, if an Ace has a value of one, a 2 of 2, etc. then you can assign values to the suits (which may or may not be multiples of 13... they don't need to be). A card can be represented as a single byte of information (or less, if you want) and the string can easily be generated from that information. Suddenly a hand of cards becomes a lot easier to manage, because it's a vector of `char` rather than a vector of `String`.

Comment: Starting with C++17 its better to use `std::size(cards)` to get size of array instead of old C idiom `sizeof(cards) / sizeof(cards[0])`.

Comment: @Bathsheba I have edit the code but that still does not compile and I am trying to find a reason why. The difference is that I am trying to create a std::vector in class whereas when I do it in main works without issues

Comment: You can only have `for` loops in functions.

Comment: @LukasPetrikas *and I am trying to find a reason why* -- The basic reason why it does not work is not one of a typo or mistake.  It is none of a general belief that you can take C++ code and paste it anywhere.  C++ is not a "scripting" language or a language that works this way -- it has a myriad of rules and regulations.  This is why it isn't recommended to learn C++ from a website -- yes, use a website to brush up on some aspect of C++ that you may not be familiar with, but don't use it as a tool in learning the language.  That's what good C++ books are for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy way:

```
std::vector<std::string> cards {
    "As","2s","3s","4s","5s","6s","7s","8s","9s","Ts","Js","Qs","Ks",
    "Ah","2h","3h","4h","5h","6h","7h","8h","9h","Th","Jh","Qh","Kh",
    "Ad","2d","3d","4d","5d","6d","7d","8d","9d","Td","Jd","Qd","Kd",
    "Ac","2c","3c","4c","5c","6c","7c","8c","9c","Tc","Jc","Qc","Kc"
};
```

and drop the separate `cards_vector` member. `cards.size()` yields the number of elements in the vector.

This uses the initialiser-list syntax of C++11.

And the compiler works out the size for you: handy if you need to add the jokers in later for example.

Comment: Thanks. That seems like the most easy solution. Could you please explain little bit what exactly is the issue with my initial attempt and why it would work when the code is called directly from main() but not work when called from class

Comment: @LukasPetrikas C++ has syntax rules, and you did not follow them.  That's the basic reason why it did not work.  To initialize class members, you failed to follow the rules for class member initialization.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie isnt that the same as the example code provided in the link? ```std::string arr[] = {"first", "sec", "third", "fourth"};
// Initialize vector with a string array
std::vector<std::string> vecOfStr(arr, arr + sizeof(arr)/sizeof(std::string));
for(std::string str : vecOfStr)
    std::cout<<str<<std::endl;```

Comment: Again, class initialization of members has differing syntax than initialization within a function (if you have `cards_vector` as a member variable).

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie That still does not fully clear to me how it works when called in main() and not work when used in a class

Comment: If that is a class member, the [member initialization list](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constructor) is used to initialize member variables.  That is totally different than when you're inside a function, and you want to initialize a variable.